# Inheritance of text boxes with the same event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create 10 or more text boxes that have the same event and logic,
instead of copy and paste it there is option to create it once and than inherit from it?
For example name1 will inherit  from name

```
<TextBox x:Name="Name" AcceptsReturn="True" AllowDrop="True"
         PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
         PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"
         SelectionChanged="listbox_SelectionChanged"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,50,0,0" 
         Grid.Row="2" />

<TextBox x:Name="name1" AcceptsReturn="True" AllowDrop="True"
         PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
         PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"
         SelectionChanged="listbox_SelectionChanged"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,50,0,0"
         Grid.Row="2" />
```

Comment: You're looking for an `ItemsControl`. Do NOT inherit from WPF UI elements unless you have a good reason to. What you're describing here is not.

Comment: So just copy paste 15 text boxes...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by HighCore in comment, `ItemsControl` might be of your help here.

Create an ***ItemsControl and set ItemTemplate to have TextBox*** inside it. (Create ObjectDataProvider to return number of textBoxes you need)

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
       <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumerableRange"
                     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                     xmlns:linq="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
                     ObjectType="{x:Type linq:Enumerable}" MethodName="Range">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                    <sys:Int32>15</sys:Int32>
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
   </Grid.Resources>

  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumerableRange}}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBox x:Name="Name"  
                      AcceptsReturn="True"
                      AllowDrop="True" 
                      PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
                      PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"
                      SelectionChanged="listbox_SelectionChanged"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25"
                      TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Grid.Column="4" 
                      Margin="0,50,0,0" Grid.Row="2"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can use *Style then to declare common properties over there and events and simply have multiple instances of TextBox* referring to that style.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
          <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
          <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
          <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
          <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,50,0,0"/>
          <EventSetter Event="PreviewDragEnter"
                       Handler="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"/>
          <EventSetter Event="PreviewDrop"
                       Handler="DropText_PreviewDrop"/>
          <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged"
                       Handler="listbox_SelectionChanged"/>
       </Style>
   </Grid.Resources>

   <TextBox x:Name="Name"/>
   <TextBox x:Name="Name1"/>
    ......
   <TextBox x:Name="Name15"/>
</Grid>
```

Note i haven't set `x:Key` on Style so it will get applied by default to all TextBoxes in your Grid. If you don't want that set `x:Key` and use that for all TextBoxes.

Comment: _"ItemsControl what you are looking for"_  - without seeing the data bindfing that's not so obvious.

Comment: I am just suggesting him. May be i should re-phrase.

Comment: HI Rohit,I didnt get the why we need the numbers and how can I call also to Name2...

Comment: Numbers are required for repition of textBoxes. Have you tried it? Also any reason for explicitly setting name? Are you going to use it in code behind?

Comment: I need to use the name explicitly since I use D&D from list box to text box and at the end I have table with mapping that store the name of the field from the list and the name of the text box which the item was dragged to.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a control template of your textbox as a resource. Mark the resource as x:Shared=False

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TxtBoxTemplate" x:Shared="False">
<Grid.Resources>
```

use this template on other instances of textbox.

```
    <TextBox x:Name="name1" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource TxtBoxTemplate}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="name2" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource TxtBoxTemplate}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="name3" Grid.Row="2" Template="{StaticResource TxtBoxTemplate}"/>
```

Complete code as follows.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TxtBoxTemplate" x:Shared="False">
            <TextBox x:Name="Name"  
                AcceptsReturn="True"
                AllowDrop="True" 
                PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
                PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"

                SelectionChanged="listbox_SelectionChanged"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,50,0,0" Grid.Row="2"
                     TextChanged="Name_OnTextChanged"
              />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="name1" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource TxtBoxTemplate}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="name2" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource TxtBoxTemplate}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="name3" Grid.Row="2" Template="{StaticResource TxtBoxTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

**# first method :** create a class with name customTextbox.cs and write down properties and events for textbox

```
public class customTextbox:TextBox
{
   public customTextbox():base()
   {
       this.AcceptsReturn = true;
       this.AllowDrop = true;
       this.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left; 
       //set your remaining propreties
       this.PreviewDragEnter +=customTextbox_PreviewDragEnter;
       this.PreviewDragLeave +=customTextbox_PreviewDragLeave;
       this.SelectionChanged += customTextbox_SelectionChanged;         
   }

   void customTextbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       //code here
   }
   private void customTextbox_PreviewDragLeave(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
   {
       //code here
   }

   private void customTextbox_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
   {
      //code here 
   }     
}
```

and in xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:hp="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">

<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <hp:customTextbox Height="100" Width="100" Grid.Row="0"></hp:customTextbox>
    <hp:customTextbox Grid.Row="1" ></hp:customTextbox>
    <hp:customTextbox Grid.Row="2" ></hp:customTextbox>
</Grid>
```

**#second method**:create a usecontrol like this(http://prntscr.com/2mren4) and replace usercontrol with textbox like below

```
<TextBox x:Class="WpfApplication3.CustomTB"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<!--set all properties and event you required inside textbox-->
```

and in .cs file use textbox instead of usercontrol like below

```
  public partial class CustomTB : TextBox
{
    public CustomTB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and in another window add

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:hp="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"> 
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>          
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>       
    <hp:CustomTB Grid.Row="0"/> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: -1 this is not winforms. subclassing UI elements without a strong reason is plain wrong.

Comment: Sir i knw this is not winform.and it works fine in wpf also.maybe you misunderstood answer.thank you